# Error: Remaining text not part of formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I want two nested statements: The first should run, then the second one. If that field is null, then display another field. But I get this error

> The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula.

Here's my code:

```
IF Workorder.Text like "*romano*"
then replace Workorder.Text, 'Black Feet' , '')
else Workorder.Text isNull then WorkOrder.Item
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `Replace()` function is missing an opening parenthesis.
2. Use `Else If` to chain statements together. `Else` by itself is not enough.
3. `IsNull()` is a function. You have to use it like: `IsNull(Workorder.Text)`